# Expectation and Variance of Stochastic Differential Equations

Tags: expectation, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

> 2. Consider the SDE
>      $$dr_t=\kappa(\theta-r_t)\,dt+\sigma dW_t,\ r_0=x,$$
>      where $\kappa$, $\theta$ and $\sigma$ are constants. You are given that the solution is
>      $$r_t=\theta+(x-\theta)e^{-\kappa t}+\sigma\int_0^te^{-\kappa(t-s)}\,dW_s.$$
>      Calculate the mean and variance of $r_t$. **You may use the result
>      $$\mathbb E\left[\left(\int_0^tY_s\,dW_s\right)^2\right]=\mathbb E\left[\int_0^tY_s^2\,ds\right],$$
>      in the calculation of the variance.**

Hi, I was wondering if somebody could tell me how to calculate the expectation of an SDE? I believe the expectation of a constant is just equal to the constant.

Comment: $M_t := \int_0^t e^{- \kappa (t-s)} \, dW_s$ is a martingale and therefore $\mathbb{E}(M_t) = \mathbb{E}(M_0)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for that, so would I only take the Expectation and variance of the integral? My lecturer didn't really explain

Comment: According to the formulation of the problem, your task is to compute mean and variance of $r_t$ and not just of the stochatsic integral.....

Comment: Yes I realised that, but how can that be done? Surely need to integrate the second term as it is continuous?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate the second term".....?

Comment: In statistics for a continuous distribution you would integrate between the bounds to get expectation

Comment: What? No! The second term is (for fixed $t$) just a constant.

Answer (score 3):

> To compute the expectation and the variance, in addition to the given
>   hint ([Ito Isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry)), you need to know that if the integrator
>   $W_t$ is an arbitrary martingale, and the integrand $f$ is bounded,
>   then the integral is a martingale, and the expectation of the integral
>   is again zero ([proof](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/martingales-and-elementary-integrals/#scn_mart_lem2)). Then we can proceed.

For: $$r_t=\theta+(x-\theta)e^{-\kappa t}+\sigma\int_0^te^{-\kappa(t-s)}\,dW_s$$

**The Expectaction of $r_t$**
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[r_t]&=\mathbb{E}\left[\theta+(x-\theta)e^{-\kappa t}+\sigma\int_0^te^{-\kappa(t-s)}\,dW_s\right]\\
&=\theta+(x-\theta)e^{-\kappa t}+\sigma\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^te^{-\kappa(t-s)}\,dW_s\right]\\
&=\theta+(x-\theta)e^{-\kappa t}
\end{align}$$

**The variance of $r_t$**

$$\begin{align}
Var[r_t]&=\mathbb{E}[r_t^2]-\left(\mathbb{E}[r_t]\right)^2\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\theta+(x-\theta)e^{-\kappa t}+\sigma\int_0^te^{-\kappa(t-s)}\,dW_s\right)^2\right]-\left(\theta+(x-\theta)e^{-\kappa t}\right)^2\\
&=(\theta+(x-\theta)e^{-\kappa t})^2+2\sigma(\theta+(x-\theta)e^{-\kappa t})^2\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^te^{-\kappa(t-s)}\,dW_s\right]+\sigma^2\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^te^{-\kappa(t-s)}\,dW_s\right)^2\right]-(\theta+(x-\theta)e^{-\kappa t})^2\\
&=\sigma^2\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^te^{-2\kappa(t-s)}\,ds\right]\\
&=\sigma^2\int_0^te^{-2\kappa(t-s)}\,ds\\
&=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{2\kappa}(1-e^{-2\kappa t})
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\IE}{\mathbb{E}}$

As $\IE(dW)=0$ you get the differential equaton for $\IE(r_t)$
$$d\IE(r_t)=\IE(dr_t)=κ(θ−\IE(r_t))dt$$
which has the solution
$$
θ−\IE(r_t)=e^{-κt}(θ−\IE(r_0))\implies \IE(r_t)=θ-e^{-κt}(θ−x)
$$

Using the Ito formula for the square
$$d(r_t)^2=2r_tκ(θ−r_t)dt+2r_tσdW_t+σ^2dt$$ 
results in
$$
d\IE(r^2_t)=(2κθ\IE(r_t)-2κ\IE(r_t^2)+σ^2)dt
$$
so that for the variance $Var(r_t)=\IE(r^2_t)-\IE(r_t)^2$ we get the differential equation
\begin{align}
d[\IE(r^2_t)-\IE(r_t)^2]&=(2κθ\IE(r_t)-2κ\IE(r_t^2)+σ^2)dt-2κ\IE(r_t)(θ−\IE(r_t))dt
\\
&=-2κ[\IE(r_t^2)-\IE(r_t)^2]dt+σ^2dt
\\
\implies
\IE(r^2_t)-\IE(r_t)^2&=\frac{σ^2}{2κ}(1-e^{-2κ}).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The SDE you have mentioned in your question is basicaly represents the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process and for OU process you can find a lot of things in the literature.

Besides the two answers given already, I will add one more that I found a year ago on this link: [expectation and the variance of OU process.](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-second-moment-or-variance-of-the-Ornstein-Uhlenbeck-process)

In a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Hope that this additional information helps somehow.